# Real Cross Ratio Example

Tags: complex-analysis

**Theorem**

The cross ratio $(z_1, z_2, z_3, z_4) $ is real if and only if the four points lie on a circle or on a straight line.

I know by geometry I can obtain $arg(z_1, z_2, z_3, z_4) = arg(\frac{z_1-z_3}{z_1-z_4}) - arg(\frac{z_2-z_3}{z_2-z_4}) $.  This difference is $0 $ or $\pm \pi$ if the points lie on a circle at relative locations.

I am trying to provide an example to this theorem.

Comment: What do you mean about the example?

Comment: what would be an applicational example that followed the conditions of this theorem?

Comment: A simple example would be $(0,1,2,3)$, whose cross-ratio is $1\in\mathbb{R}$, and all of these points are on a straight line.